# Converting Go []interface{} to protobuf Repeated Array

Tags: go, proto, protobuf-go

I have a service written in Go that get data from rest api and return that data as a grpc server. I got an array of object. And I want to return  it through the grpc protobuf file. But it keeps failing because of type issue as the data from the api is []interface{} and I don't know how to return this through protobuf response.

Below is the go lang code

```
        return &waas.BankListResponse{ 
                 Status:  result.Data["Status"].(bool), 
                 Message: result.Data["Message"].(string), 
                 Data: result.Data["banks"].([]*waas.Banks), 
         }, nil
```

The proto file

```
message banks { 
   string bankCode = 1; 
   string bankName = 2; 
 } 
   message BankListResponse { 
     bool Status =1; 
     string Message = 2; 
     repeated banks data = 3; 
   }
```

So the `result.Data["bank"]` is the array of banks and the data type is `[]interface{}`
sample data

```
{
  "banks": [
    {                        
      "bankCode":"",                         
      "bankName":""
    },
    {                        
      "bankCode":"",                         
      "bankName":""
    }
   ]
}
```

So can someone assist me point out how return such data on the proto file.

Answer (score 0):

you need to write custom code to transfer data from the interface to your proto object. you will return this new proto object as the response.

Comment: Can give a code sample